# How to get the error body from an ApolloHttpException?

Tags: apollo-kotlin

With Apollo Kotlin 3 the `ApolloHttpException` there is no `rawResponse()` method anymore and the `body` property is always null.

Is there a way to get the error body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://apollographql.github.io/apollo-kotlin/kdoc/apollo-api/com.apollographql.apollo3.exception/-apollo-http-exception/index.html), the HTTP error body, by default, is always null. You can opt-in `exposeHttpErrorBody` in `HttpNetworkTransport` if you need it. If you're doing this, you **must** call `BufferedSource.close` on `body` to avoid sockets and other resources leaking.

To do this, when you are creating the Apollo client, you have to set `.httpExposeErrorBody()` to `true`:

```kotlin
ApolloClient.Builder()
            .serverUrl(graphQlUrl)
            .httpExposeErrorBody(true)
            .build()
```

If you're setting it to `true`, you **must** catch `ApolloHttpException` and close the body explicitly to avoid sockets and other resources leaking.